# dynamic linq to entities to comply with DRY

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

Is there a way to do the below dynamically so I don't have to repeat myself?

```
var result = from c in _Entities.Cars 
where c.Colour == "White"
select c;

var result = from m in _Entities.Bikes 
where m.Colour == "White"
select m;

etc...
```

as in:

```
var entities = new List<string> {"Cars", "Bikes"};
foreach (var e in entities)
{
    var result = from m in e //pseudo code
    where m.Colour == "White"
    select m;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Cars and Bikes implement a common interface, say IVehicle, which has the Colour property, you could define a function:

```
public IEnumerable<IVehicle> GetWhiteVehicles(IEnumerable<IVehicle> vehicles) {
  return vehicles.Where(p => p.Colour == "White");
}
```

and then

```
var result = GetWhiteVehicles(_Entities.Cars);
var result = GetWhiteVehicles(_Entities.Bikes);
```

If Cars and Bikes are generated classes from Entity Framework, you can nevertheless make them implement an interface by adding a new source file with a partial definition of the classes with the same name:

```
public partial class Bikes : IVehicle { }
public partial class Cars : IVehicle { }
```

Comment: yeah but I need the return type from GetWhiteVehicles to be List<Car>, Lis<Bike>, etc..

Comment: They are of that type, it's not just specified. Just define the variables explicitly: List<Cars> result = GetWhiteVehicles(_Entities.Cars).ToList(); or add the ToList() inside the function

Comment: another thing. my classes are indeed generated from Entity Framework. What do you mean with adding a new source file?

Comment: Or to make it a little bit more abstract: public List<T> GetWhiteVehicles<T>(IEnumerable<T> vehicles) where T : class, IVehicle {
  return vehicles.Where(p => p.Colour == "White").ToList();
}

Comment: @user441365: Entity Framework generated a file, say Bikes.cs. You don't want to change that file, because next time you generate the entities, your changes are lost. So you just create a new file, say Bikes.Custom.cs and put your additions in there (public partial class Bikes : IVehicle { }). So Bikes always implements your Interface, even when Entity Framework changes your Bikes.cs file due to regeneration.

Comment: yeah I follow what you mean but when I create this class with the partials implementing the interface it doesn't seem to know about the EF generated classes, so when I reference them in the code they don't seem to be recognised... you know what I mean?

Comment: There's no need to break this away from EF and do the filtering in memory on the entire table each time by using `IEnumerable<T>`. Use `IQueryable<T>` so you can do the `Where` on the database.

Comment: sorry what I mean is that I can't make the EF classes to implement this interface. I tried creating a separate file for the classes and declare them as partial and then implement the interface but they don't seem to recognise the parent EF class..

Comment: @user441365 that shouldn't be an issue. (And it shouldn't be a "parent" class"). I'll add a bit on that to my answer since I also use such an interface.

Comment: ok I think I got it working now... one more thing though. Is it possible to add all the entities in a list and then loop through it instead of calling them one by one as in your answer: var result = GetWhiteVehicles(_Entities.Cars);    
var result = GetWhiteVehicles(_Entities.Bikes); .... etc...

Comment: You could have a `List<IQueryable<IVehicle>>` and work on that and then `Union` them in the output. It would make the flaw of using `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable` here even more costly if you are going to be using several such types. The results selected back would have to be cast before you could do anything with them other than what that interface defines though.

Comment: ok I'm using the List<IQueryable<IVehicle>> to do the loop but how could I cast the "_entities.Cars" back to the original Type so I can add objects to it ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var entities = new List<List<dynamic>> {_Entities.Cars.ToList<dynamic>(), _Entitites.Bikes.ToList<dynamic>()};
foreach (var l in entities)
{
    var result = from m in l
        where m.Colour == "White"
        select m;
}
```

Thus you avoid any changes to your business-modell. However hence the `dynamic`-type is only resolved at runtime there is no way to ensure that the property `Colour` really exists on that type.

Comment: @user441365 Now it should

Comment: I'd avoid using reflection when it isn't necessary.

Comment: @JonHanna There is no refelction involved. However it has the same disadvantages as it cannot be guaranteed that `Colour` really exists on the instance.

Comment: yeah and the return value is dynamic instead of the actual Car entity

Comment: @user441365 feel free to cast it.

Comment: `dynamic` is reflection (though it's not big-R Reflection as specifically called in .NET), all those calls to `Binder` still have to be created by reflecting upon the type. And you've dragged them all into memory. What if there are thousands of cars and bikes but only a handful that are white? Hitting the database for every single car and bike is excessive.

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface that contains color (IColorful). Set your cars and bikes to implement that interface. Make and call a function:

```
List<IColorful> FindByColor(IEnumerable<IColorful> list, string color)
{
    List<IColorful> result = list.Where(item => item.Color == color).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Call it like so:

```
var entities = FindByColor(_Entities.Cars, color);
entities.AddRange(FindByColor(_Entities.Bikes, color))
```

Comment: Why do this in memory, and not on the database?

Answer (score 0):

First either define a base class they both derive from, or an interface they both implement. I'm going to assume from here in they implement a `IColoured` interface with a `Colour` property. (Though I'll note that it's common to use en-US in member names, so colours are represented by a `Color` property).

So, say your Cars class was created by EF as:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
  public partial class Cars
  {
    /*…*/
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    /*…*/
  }
}
```

Then you can have a file with:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
  public partial class Cars : IColoured
  {
  }
}
```

Because the two `partial` pieces of code are combined in compiling the class definition your code just needs to indicate the interface is implemented, the fact that the matching property is in another file doesn't matter.

Then:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterByColour<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string colour)
  where T : IColoured
{
  return source.Where(p => p.Colour == colour);
}
```

Now you can use `_Entities.Cars.FilterByColour("white")`, `_Entities.Bikes.FilterByColour("blue")` etc. If filtering by `"white"` was a particularly common case then either:

**Important:** Never define such a method as taking an `IEnumerable<>` if it you don't have a good reason to (such as using something that isn't compatible with EF), use `IQueryable<>` so it is still being processed by EF and can be filtered on the database, rather than having everything retrieved from the database and filtered in your application.

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterWhite<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
  where T : IColoured
{
  return source.FilterByColour("white");
}
```

Or if you had no other use for FilterByColour then:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterWhite<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
  where T : IColoured
{
  return source.Where(p => p.Colour == "white");
}
```

Would work.